# collapsing ngbDropdown menu items on mouse leave

Tags: drop-down-menu, ng-bootstrap

I have a problem implementing the menu with ngbDropdown.
Sub menus are supposed to toggle based on mouse enter and mouse leave events.
It is achieved by using `(mouseenter)="deviceDrop.open()"` and `(mouseleave)` which basically works however menu is not collapsing if I hoover another one:

[image]

```html
<div ngbDropdown #deviceDrop="ngbDropdown">
  <button ngbDropdownAnchor (mouseenter)="deviceDrop.open()"> Devices </button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu
       (mouseleave)="$event.stopPropagation(); deviceDrop.close();">
    <button ngbDropdownItem [routerLink]="['devices']">
      Manage devices
    </button>
    <!-- here go other sub menu items  -->
  </div>
   <!-- here other top-level menu items  -->
</div>
```

Can you advise me on how to avoid this annoying effect?

Comment: thanks. ngbDropdown #deviceDrop="ngbDropdown" helped me solve my problem (I dont have nested menus)